# onReceive Broadcast on 8.1.0

Tags: java, android

I have a working broadcast on a physical Android 8.0 (API 26) device as well as an 8.0 emulator. It does not work on Android 8.1.0 emulator or physical device.

I also tried registering the receiver but still not working.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction("com.my.receiver");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Helpers.MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.my.receiver"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

The Java class that you specify here is `MainActivity`.

```
android:name=".Helpers.MyReceiver"
```

The Java class that you specify here is `.Helpers.MyReceiver`.

These are not the same. This receiver will not receive this broadcast on any version of Android, let alone Android 8.1.

Comment: Works as expected on anything less than api 27.  "I have a working broadcast on a physical Android 8.0 (API 26) device as well as an 8.0 emulator."

Comment: @EdwardDiGirolamo: "Works as expected on anything less than api 27" -- the code in your question does not. Perhaps you are running different code than you have in your question. Or, perhaps you are sending the real broadcast somewhere else (as `MainActivity` is a *very* strange name for a `BroadcastReceiver` subclass).